# Opposite of 歯止め?

Tags: word-choice, translation, expressions, idioms, metaphor

According to WWWJDIC, 歯止め is used as follows:

> 歯止めをかける; 歯止めを掛ける (exp,v1) to curb; to halt; to apply brakes; to put an end to

The English translations have a pretty good correspondence with the imagery, especially if you consider 歯車.

Consider the opposite action:

> To get things moving; to get it in drive; to weigh anchor; to find purchase; to stop spinning wheels; to find traction; to [actually] get started; to get underway

What would be a Japanese expression that corresponds? 取りかかる, 緒に就く, 切り口, and 糸口 all come to mind, but they're still not quite right. The physical lurch when a vehicle or mechanism starts delivering power is the key to all of these English expressions; I would like to get as close as possible while staying within natural expressions.

Comment: Maybe 踏み込む ? (I lack the confidence to make this an answer)

Comment: Perhaps 計画を軌道に乗せる ; to put a plan into action, or more literally, into orbit.

Comment: @Tim Want to add it as an answer? Now that you mention it, I do remember that phrase in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be 拍車をかける, which means to spur, encourage, accelerate etc.